# Stepper Motor current rating and microstepping

Tags: stepper-motor, microstepping

I am working with stepper for first time and want some suggestions. Motor runs smooth but the problem is it gets hot after a few seconds. reason may be that i am giving it a bit higher than the rated current. I am planning to limit current to 0.31 Amp as rated. Please help me understand would it be possible to go for microstepping with this limited current? or motor requires more current in microstepping modes?

Comment: this link : http://www.geckodrive.com/support/step-motor-basics.html will help you to understand the relationship between the motor torque and the rated current, if you apply to much current you risk to damage your stepper motor see the figure 1.

Comment: Huh? The problem is, as you say, you are exceeding the rated current. Solution: don't do that!

Comment: Most steppers I've used are designed to run hot. What temperature does the data sheet say, and what current is it drawing?

Comment: @PhilFrost yeah but the problem is I am not sure will microstepping work if I limit the current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not exceed the maximum current listed in the motor's datasheet. Exceeding the current limit is not a requirement for microstepping. Exceeding the current limit is, however, a good way to damage your motor.